# Building Graph in QGIS for Service Area computing

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, graph, service-area

I do have

- a vector shapefile with a streets network
- a point shapefile with 5 supermarkets as points

Everything is right now in WGS 84.

I would like to perform QNEAT's `"ISO AREA AS POLYGON from Layer"` around my Supermarkets.

First, I think I have to build a graph from my streets Layer. But that requires a projected CRS such as UTM 32 N?
How to transform WGS correctly in UTM 32 N under QGIS? (Got only failures)

Then I have to perform "Build Graph" on the Streets UTM32N? Right?
And then I can perform ISO Area on both shapefiles.
The supermarkets must be in UTM 32 N as well, but otherwise, they can stay as a vector layer, is not it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are on the right way with your worksteps. But you should consider the following advice:

**@ Graph building:** QNEAT3 works a little different than other network analysis tools such as ArcGIS Network Analyst. The network analyst requires you to build a graph before performing analysis. In QGIS it is currently not possible to save a built graph to disk (eg. as built graph file, etc.). Therefore all QNEAT3 Plugins (as of Version 1.0.1) run the building process as part of each algorithm. The graph is therefore built every time you call an algorithm.

**@ Performing Iso Area as Polygon from Layer:** This algorithm currently needs to run with layers in projected coordinate systems. This is due to limitations that occur inside the QGIS interpolation classes (see [notes in the documentation](https://root676.github.io/IsoAreaAlgs.html)). You can easily project your layers to `UTM32N` by choosing the `save as` functionality when right clicking on a layer. In the following dialog, just select `UTM32N` as coordinate system and save the layer to disk. Then use the projected layers as input for the QNEAT3 algorithm. You have to reproject both, network and point layer, in order to get the algorithm to work.